# jQuery click for a link but having to click twice for it to work?

Tags: jquery

i have this piece of code which grabs the id and passes to the plugin call  but you have to click it twice to work any ideas?

```
// Let's setup the video overlay's (if any)
    jQuery('a.play').on("click", function() {
        var videoUrl = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        jQuery("a.play").dojoVideo({
                'videoid' : videoUrl,
                'videoplayer' : 'youtube', // options - youtube or vimeo
                'width' : '800px', // video width
                'height' : '450px', // video height
                'autoplay' : 'true'// options - true or false
            });
            return false
    });
```

I noticed in the plugin it  has a click function but not sure how to change this so i use mine instead as a need to get the id and pass it as i am doing.

```
jQuery.fn.dojoVideo = function (options) {

    var settings = { // Defaults
        'videoid' : '',
        'videoplayer' : 'youtube',
        'width' : '530px',
        'height' : '330px',
        'autoplay' : 'false'
    };

    return this.each(function() {        
       // If options exist, lets merge them
      // with our default settings
      if ( options ) { 
        $.extend(settings, options);
      }

    function centerS(cur) {

        var cur = cur;

        cur.css("position","absolute");
        cur.css("top", ( $(window).height() - cur.height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
        cur.css("left", ( $(window).width() - cur.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
        return this;
    }

    $(this).click(function(){
        var a=$(document).height();
     var b=$(window).width();
        var popuphtml = '<div id="dvGlobalMask"></div><div id="dojoVideo"><div class="modalnav"></div><div id="videocontent"></div></div>';
        $('body').append(popuphtml);
        $("#dvGlobalMask").css({width:b,height:a});
        $("#dvGlobalMask").fadeTo("fast",0.4);

        $('#dojoVideo').css('width' , settings.width);
        $('#dojoVideo').css('height' , settings.height);
        centerS($("#dojoVideo"));

        var autoplay = 0;
        if (settings.autoplay == 'true') {
            autoplay = 1;
        } else {
            autoplay = 0;
        }
        // Checks for the type of video that is being pulled.
        youtubestr = '<iframe width="' + settings.width + '" height="' + settings.height + '" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + settings.videoid + '?autoplay=' + autoplay + '&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
        vimeostr = '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + settings.videoid + '?color=00adef&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;autoplay=' + autoplay + '" width="' + settings.width + '" height="' + settings.height + '" frameborder="0"></iframe>';

        switch (settings.videoplayer) {
            case 'youtube' :
                $("#videocontent").html($(youtubestr));
            break;
            case 'vimeo' :
                $("#videocontent").html($(vimeostr));
            break;
        }

        $("#dojoVideo").show();
        $('.modalnav').show();
        //$(settings.videoid).show();
        }); 

        $('.modalnav').live('click', function(){
            $('#dvGlobalMask').hide();
            $('#dojoVideo').hide();
            $('.modalnav').hide();
            $('#videocontent').html('');
            $(settings.videoid).hide();
        });
    });

    return this;
}
```

Comment: Could you include the URL to the docs of the plugin?

Comment: http://codecanyon.net/item/youtube-vimeo-popup-plugin/306502?WT.ac=item_more_thumb&WT.seg_1=item_more_thumb&WT.z_author=wrwipeout - in their examples it is just calling id right into the array but i added passing the id to it - in the examples they dont need click functions as i think it does this already so that might be the cause.

Comment: From the looks of things, this plugin is adding a click handler itself, so you don't need to use your own. Try this, in place of the line where you're setting the click handler: `jQuery("document").on("ready", function() {` Keep everything else the same.

Comment: how can i pass the ID from the link to the array though?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using 3 plugin functions to each link with a separate class due to having to complete this in a small time frame - i will however modify the plugin so it is more flexible at a later date and will update this post with a better answer.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
jQuery('a.play').click( function() {
```

(basically you want to remove the .on and replace it with .click, then remove "click" before the function.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: There is no difference, other than `on()` being the reccommended way to attach event handlers

Comment: IIRC - `.click()` uses `.on('click')` internally

Comment: it was just click before and had the same problem :)

Comment: do you have a link you can share?

Comment: ive updated question, its got a click in the plugin but guess i need to change this?

Comment: I assume that you have multiple videos on the page and you don't want to write multiple functions to load each video right? In the event that you have only one video per page, you could take this approach.  I made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robbiegod/Dj5Xz/1/

Comment: who could i change that to work with multiple videos?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41713/discussion-between-robbiegod-and-james-brandon)